# Кафе-столовая открыто или открыта?

Tags: синтаксис

-

Comment: Да, вопрос оказался сложным... Непонятно только, что это за монстр такой "Кафе-столовая". Выбрали бы уж что-нибудь одно... ;-))

Answer (score 1):

Если в двух словах, это один из редких случаев, когда грамматический род находится в состоянии становления. Т.е. оба варианта правильны.

Вообще говоря, род существительных с дефисным написанием обычно определяется следующим образом. Если первая часть несклоняема (жар-птица, шеф-повар) то род определяется второй чатью. Иначе, если обе части склоняемы (ракета-носитель, кресло-кровать), то определяющим являеется второе слово.
Правило это - скорее приём для запоминания, первопричина глубже. Правильнее будет сказать, что в дефисных сочетаниях с несклоняемой первой частью основной смысл обычно падает на вторую часть, иначе на первую. И именно этот смысл является определяющим грамматический род. Тем не менее это правило достаточно универсально. 
Сложности возникают в двух случаях. Во-первых, когда вариант склонения не определяется автоматически (царь-девица, плащ-палатка, счет-фактура) и когда первое слово не изменяется по падежам не только в данном сочетании, но и в принципе (пальто-пелерина, кафе-столовая, суши-ресторан). Последний случай вообще неразрешим грамматически, остаётся только смотреть аналогии или искать в паре главное смыслонесущее слово.

У Лопатина слова пальто-пелерина и кафе-столовая даются в разном оформлении:

**пальто-пелерина, пальто-пелерины

и

кафе-столовая, -ой.**

Из сопоставления можно заключить, что во втором случае предполагается несклоняемость первого слова в сочетании, т.е. логическое ударение падает на второе слово. Следовательно, кафе-столовая по Лопатину - женского рода. 
Но я бы с этим выводом не спешил. Построенные по аналогии слова (бар-ресторан, гостинница-мотель и т.п.) явно тяготеют к склоняемости обеих частей. Значит, будь на месте кафе изменяемое по падежам слово, оно по обшему правилу считалось бы главным и определяло бы средний род дефисного слова. 
Из всего сказанного и вытекает утрверждение о неустоявшемся грамматическом роде слова "кафе-столовая". И, следовательно, возможность использования и среднего, и женского рода.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что род тут определяется по последнему слову - "столовая". То есть, все-таки "открыта".

Answer (score 0):

"Иначе, если обе части склоняемы (ракета-носитель, кресло-кровать), то определяющим являеется второе слово". - Наоборот, определяющим является первое слово, потому что склоняется, и ракета-носитель будет "она".
Что касается "кафе-столовой", то "столовая" - слово, включающее в себя более широкое понятие, да и "кафе" - НЕ СКЛОНЯЕТСя, так что "кафе-столовая" все-таки "моя"

Comment: Я об этом правиле писал подробно. А "кафе" не склоняется в сочетании  только потому, что не склоняется вообще. Тоже писал об этом. Будь на месте "кафе", скжем "кафетрий", вы бы могли поручится, что главным словом и тут будет "столовая"? Я  - нет.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, определяющим род здесь будет первое слово. 
"В этом кафе-столовой", "этому кафе-столовой". "Наше кафе-столовая уже открыто".